# Load SSL dynamically with code

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl

My question is so far, a purely theoretical one.
I want to make a CMS that supports multiple sites.

The question I haven't been able to figure out so far is this one:
How do I attach the ssl certificate for https protocol from the code-behind, instead of attaching it through the hosting interface or on the iis itself (the main problem is that i want a different ssl certificate for every site, instead grouping them on one certificate, which allows maximum of 5 domains, and will still say they are the same entity)

Comment: are you willing to run each site on a different port?

Comment: I would separate the CMS application with SSL (which to me, is a deployment concern).  Just remember that SSL certs expire.  Are you going to manage that?

Comment: I can figure out managing them with some kind of alert system, if i can make them work in the first place. As for the multiple port/ip solution, i believe that will cause a lot of complication in the setup and will require me to have dedicated hosting (something im not willing to go for at this early stage)

Comment: Worrying about SSL might be best left until after you have dedicated hosting. Assuming you have dedicated hosting, SSL certs are then assigned to domains which map to IP(s). Your code should never need to know anythign about your cert, only whether or not you require SSL for each function of the site. For example, in MVC you would use the `[RequireHttps]` attribute to indicate a certain action is only available through SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not solvable on ASP.NET level.

The reason is that with HTTPS requests the SSL handshake (where certificates are presented) is performed before the client sends HTTP request, from which you can learn the domain.

The only exception is server-name-indication extension in TLS, which lets the client specify the desired domain in SSL request. But this extension is not supported by many clients and it's not present in still used SSL3 protocol version. And even with this extension it's the SSL server that decides which certificate to present.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Eugene, administering the SSL cert is beyond the level of ASP.Net; however, you may create some form of administration routine to execute the command-line tool for IIS7 (and up) AppCmd.exe to manage the certs:

ie (shell command --security rights is important):
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='Default Web Site'].bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:']" /commit:apphost

The System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate namespace might also come in handy.